# keras - ожидался другой ответ

Tags: python, keras

Входные данные по типу

```
x_train = array([[1.3590000e+03, 1.3180000e+03, 1.7082020e+07, 1.2000000e+03], [4.0380000e+03, 4.6170000e+03, 1.7082020e+07, 1.2000000e+03], [2.6300000e+03, 3.9840000e+03, 1.7082020e+07, 1.0540000e+03], [3.4460000e+03, 4.5310000e+03, 1.8102014e+07, 2.1610000e+03], [9.1500000e+02, 4.5310000e+03, 1.8102014e+07, 2.1610000e+03], [3.4460000e+03, 4.4570000e+03, 1.8102014e+07, 2.1610000e+03]])
y_train = array([[ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2., 2.], [16., 2., 1.], [16., 4., 1.], [16., 0., 1.]])
но результат [[1616849.4   1550158.4     54270.72 ]
 [1616645.    1549958.6     54247.965]
 [1530179.1   1467063.      51288.938]
 [1529552.4   1466477.8     51272.31 ]
 [1531608.9   1468432.5     51389.453]
 [1529679.2   1466598.      51271.816]
 [1529510.4   1466437.1     51267.277]
 [1531926.    1468735.9     51406.277]
 [1529213.1   1466153.1     51250.47 ]
 [1529175.5   1466111.1     51226.37 ]
 [1529424.9   1466356.1     51264.93 ]
 [1531726.    1468537.9     51373.17 ]
 [1531182.4   1468027.1     51378.06 ]
 [1532010.6   1468815.6     51411.83 ]
 [1531546.9   1468376.6     51398.44 ]
 [1531727.9   1468543.2     51385.023]
 [1447227.9   1387525.2     48541.914]
 [1447429.9   1387724.8     48575.203]
 [1447145.4   1387455.6     48571.164]
 [1444912.    1385329.5     48432.594]
 [1446700.2   1387032.      48556.8  ]
 [1446735.2   1387061.6     48540.684]
 [1445760.2   1386125.1     48466.57 ]]# как обучить нейроную сеть близку к результату y_train ?
```

код:

```
x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy')
wb = None
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py

# Среднее значение
mean = x_train.mean(axis=0)
# Стандартное отклонение
std = x_train.std(axis=0)
x_train -= mean
x_train /= std

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))#shape 1
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
x_test, y_test = importdata()
mse, mae = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Средняя абсолютная ошибка (тысяч долларов):", mae)
pred = model.predict(x_test)

print("Предсказанная стоимость:", pred*-1, ", правильная стоимость:", y_test)
```

Comment: Что значит "не тот вывод"? Какой есть и какой должен быть?

Comment: "не тот вывод" - ожидался другой ответ ..

Comment: Ну так это и есть мой второй вопрос. Используйте кнопку править

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы же нормализуете `x_train`, а `x_test` не нормализуете. **Предобработка тренировочных и тестовых входных данных должна совпадать**, иначе и правда ерунда получится.

```
x_test, y_test = importdata()
# добавил нормализацию
x_test -= mean
x_test /= std
```

Нужно ли вычислять `mean` и `std` для `x_text` заново - вопрос нетривиальный, но по идее, если данные из одной генеральной совокупности, у них эти значения не должны сильно отличаться. Обычно для преобразования тестовых данных используют функцию преобразования, "натренированную" на тренировочных данных, то есть вычислять их заново не нужно. Но можно попробовать и так и так.

Не исключаю, что вы уже делаете нормализацию в функции `importdata`, но из приведённого кода это узнать невозможно. Хотя если судить по вашим предсказаниям - нормализации тестовых данных у вас точно нет.

И отдельно непонятно, зачем вы печатаете `pred*-1` (то есть по сути `-pred`), а не просто `pred`.

Потестировал в варианте `x_test, y_test = x_train.copy(), y_train.copy()` с нормализацией, получил вполне терпимую ошибку:

```
Средняя абсолютная ошибка (тысяч долларов): 0.13467107713222504
```

Если увеличить число эпох (для повышения точности) и размер батча (для повышения скорости расчётов), то результат вообще отличный (хотя и сильно варьируется с каждым запуском):

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2000, batch_size=20, verbose=0)

Средняя абсолютная ошибка (тысяч долларов): 0.001550681539811194
```

Comment: при нормализации данных получил:  [[7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [6.581648  5.627339  1.4382766]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [6.5488234 5.5973387 1.437735 ]
 [6.615987  5.658723  1.4388433]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [6.7741213 5.8032503 1.4414527]
 [6.892623  5.911555  1.4434083]
 [6.6503396 5.6901193 1.4394102]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
 [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
Ответы какие-то однотипные. А что может быть еще не так ?

Comment: @tormozzzz Покажите x_test, без данных только гадать можно. Может быть у вас в тесте данные не похожи почему-то на трейн, не было возможности у сетки научиться таким данным, мало ли что бывает.

Comment: x_test = array([[5.036000e+03, 5.474000e+03, 1.908202e+07, 1.200000e+03],       [4.617000e+03, 3.984000e+03, 1.908202e+07, 1.200000e+03],       [8.260000e+02, 5.890000e+02, 1.808202e+07, 1.812000e+03],       [4.318000e+03, 4.038000e+03,

Comment: y_test = array([[2., 1., 1.],       [0., 2., 2.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [0., 1., 2.],       [0., 1., 2.],       [2., 1., 1.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [2., 1., 1.],       [2., 1., 1.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [0., 2., 2.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [2., 0., 1.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [1., 2., 2.],       [1., 3., 2.]])

Comment: у меня приблизительно loss: 30.2735 - mae: 4.2831

Comment: https://transfiles.ru/fr755 - x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy')

Comment: @tormozzzz Ну я думаю, что во-первых у вас видимо не очень консистентные данные, у вас точно тест имеет то же распределение, что трейн, откуда вы данные вообще берёте? Я вот что-то не уверен. А во-вторых вы стреляете из пушки по воробьям. Возьмите для начала линейную регрессию, потом с регуляризацией. Нейросети на таком малом количестве данных легко переобучаются, не для них такие мелкие задачи.

Comment: train и test взяты из одной бд. 55 тыс данных - в примерах по нейронным сетям я видел и 5 тыс данных

Comment: @tormozzzz Ну, в общем это другой вопрос уже, более нетривиальный. Если интересен ответ - этот вопрос уже не трогайте, задавайте новый. "Как улучшить качество предсказания? Вот мои данные, скачать здесь. У меня таким-то методом получилось столько-то." Я как доберусь до ноутбука попробую посмотреть, что вы выложили по ссылке, покрутить. Но обычно нейросети применяют когда знают, что делают. Сначала попроще методы берут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168442/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-keras - задал)

Comment: @tormozzzz Хорошо, но надо ещё постараться над вопросом - вон уже минусовать начали