# Как улучшить качество предсказания? (keras)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py
x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy') 
# Среднее значение
mean = x_train.mean(axis=0)
# Стандартное отклонение
std = x_train.std(axis=0)
x_train -= mean
x_train /= std
x_test,y_test = np.load('datsx_test.npy'),np.load('datsy_test.npy')
x_test -= mean
x_test /= std
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))#shape 1
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=20, verbose=2)

mse, mae = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Средняя абсолютная ошибка (тысяч долларов):", mae)
pred = model.predict(x_test)

print("Предсказанная стоимость:", pred, ", правильная стоимость:", y_test)
```

Я получил:

```
pred =  [[7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.581648 5.627339 1.4382766] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.5488234 5.5973387 1.437735 ] [6.615987 5.658723 1.4388433] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.7741213 5.8032503 1.4414527] [6.892623 5.911555 1.4434083] [6.6503396 5.6901193 1.4394102] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
```

pred должен быть почти

```
y_test = [[2., 1., 1.], [0., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.], [2., 1., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 1., 1.], [2., 1., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [0., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 3., 2.]]`
```

Данные для:

```
x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy')
x_test,y_test = np.load('datsx_test.npy'),np.load('datsy_test.npy')
```

можно скачать от сюда :https://transfiles.ru/pn2om

Comment: Приведите ваши данные и задачу

Comment: По ссылке и трейн и тест есть? Как-то отдельно обозначьте в тексте вопроса где брать данные, в комментарии кода не все смотрят.
Какое у вас получилось качество напишите, и что именно вас не устраивает.

Comment: @CrazyElf - все исправил

Comment: @dIm0n - все исправил

Comment: @tormozzzz Только завтра смогу данные скачать посмотреть. Вообще навскидку можно попробовать Dropout слоёв добавить, чтобы переобучение понизить

Comment: @CrazyElf - я слои пробывал добавлять, не особо помогло. Спасибо вам )

Comment: @tormozzzz А использовать именно нейросети - это принципиально в вашем случае? Всё-таки по-хорошему надо начинать с изучения распределения данных, потом пробовать линейную регрессию, потом ещё методы посложнее и только потом нейросети. Без понимания своих данных вы нейросетями много не наловите )

Comment: @CrazyElf - В моём случае возможно нейросети дадут наиболее точный ответ) И как по мне нейросети наиболее наверное универсальный инструмент. А так спасибо за совет )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я покрутил по-всякому ваши данные и могу вам сказать, что с такими данными не помогут никакие нейросети. В ваших данных просто практически нет зависимости компонент `y` от компонент `x`, вот графики (в гриде по вертикали идут по очереди 4 компоненты `x`, по горизонтали - компоненты `y`, на самих же графиках снизу `x`, слева `y`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите - никаких намёков на диагонали в рисунке, т.е. практически нет никакой вообще зависимости `y` от `x` ни по одной из компонент. В такой ситуации всё, что можно сделать - это предсказать для каждой компоненты `y` просто "среднюю температуру по больнице", что в итоге и будет делать любой метод машинного обучения, который вы примените. И я даже могу это показать:

```
print(np.mean(y_train, axis=0))
array([7.29743973, 6.33168606, 1.43495386])
```

Видите? Очень похоже на тот прогноз, который получили вы, при том, что я тут просто взял "среднюю температуру по больнице" отдельно для каждой компоненты `y`. Да, за счёт усложнения модели можно получить чуть-чуть лучшую метрику на тренировочных данных, но не надо себя обманывать - это будет ерунда, а не результат, случайные флуктуации. В ваших данных просто нет сигнала, которому можно научиться, чтобы его предсказывать. Почему так - я не знаю, разбирайтесь с вашими данными.

Вот ещё матрица корреляции, первые 4 компоненты - это компоненты `x`, последние 3 - компоненты `y`, и тут опять же видно, что какая-то корреляция есть только у компонент `y` между собой, а компоненты `x` не коррелируют вообще ни с чем, кроме самих себя, они не коррелируют даже с другими компонентами `x`, не говоря уже о корреляции с компонентами `y`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: интересно почему данные не коррелируют)

Comment: Ну тут надо разбираться - что за данные, где вы их взяли. Может источник данных неправильный, может обработка кривая, а может и правда данные независимые, что очень странно - обычно скорее проблема бывает в ложных корреляциях, а не в их полном отсутствии