# В чём ошибка ?(keras)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

Мой способ решения задачи:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py
x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy') 
# Среднее значение
mean = x_train.mean(axis=0)
# Стандартное отклонение
std = x_train.std(axis=0)
x_train -= mean
x_train /= std
x_test,y_test = np.load('datsx_test.npy'),np.load('datsy_test.npy')
x_test -= mean
x_test /= std
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))#shape 1
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=20, verbose=2)

mse, mae = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Средняя абсолютная ошибка (тысяч долларов):", mae)
pred = model.predict(x_test)

print("Предсказанная стоимость:", pred, ", правильная стоимость:", y_test)
```

Я получил:

```
pred =  [[7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.581648 5.627339 1.4382766] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.5488234 5.5973387 1.437735 ] [6.615987 5.658723 1.4388433] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [6.7741213 5.8032503 1.4414527] [6.892623 5.911555 1.4434083] [6.6503396 5.6901193 1.4394102] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983] [7.5767965 6.5368557 1.4546983]
```

pred должен быть почти

```
y_test = [[2., 1., 1.], [0., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [0., 1., 2.], [0., 1., 2.], [2., 1., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 1., 1.], [2., 1., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [0., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 2.], [1., 3., 2.]]
```

Данные для:

```
x_train,y_train = np.load('datsx.npy'),np.load('datsy.npy')
x_test,y_test = np.load('datsx_test.npy'),np.load('datsy_test.npy')
```

можно скачать от сюда :https://transfiles.ru/pn2om

где x_train = [q w e r] y_train = [t y u]

И задача такая что есть игра между 2 командами в матче

- q - номер    первой команды
- w - номер 2 команды
- e - дата матча записанная в виде    17082020
- r - номер матча
- t - очки первой команды
- y - очки второй команды
- u - 1 если победитель    первая команда, 2 если победитель 2 команда
  и 3 если ничья

нужно предсказать y_train при известном x_train

Comment: А причем тут корреляция?

Comment: @ passant - моё предположение почему ответ не правильный выдает нейронная сеть...

Comment: Вы общепринятое значение слова "корреляция" знаете?    Если "да" -  то что такое "корреляция ДЛЯ сетей"? И если знаете, что в чем собственно ваш вопрос состоит?

Comment: @ passant  - предполагаю что корреляция это не правильные входные данные которые между собой не связаны какой-то связью ... А как правильно мне задать вопрос ?

Comment: 1. Что значит "неправильные входные данные"? Ну, дайте правильные. 2. Что-бы проверить корреляцию -  на надо городить огород с Keras. Достаточно вычислить коэффициент корреляции. 3. Задать вопрос правильно - это задать его так, что бы в конце можно было поставить знак вопроса.

Comment: @passant - ok, спасибо)

Comment: Так вам же все уже объяснили, оказывается. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168442/Как-улучшить-качество-предсказания-keras  Зачем спрашивать повторно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как улучшить качество предсказания? (keras)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168442/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-keras)